# How can I upgrade my jailbroken and unlocked iPhone 3GS to 4.2?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, unlock

I have an iPhone 3GS running on 4.0.1 and I want to upgrade it to 4.2 with my Mac. How can I go about doing this?

- Current Version: 4.0.1 (8A306)
- Model: MB7...
- Modem Firmware: 05.13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special to upgrading when jailbroken or not. You must use the official upgrade path which means losing unlock and jailbreak, and then re-jailbreak and re-unlock if you want and if it is possible with the new firmware. So...

1. Plug it in
2. Follow the prompts in iTunes

Comment: Is it possible with the new firmware? I thought there was something special that you had to do.

Comment: @michael it is possible and there is something special, only about 3GS. for more info: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/is-there-a-jailbreak-for-ios-4-2/5276#5276